# Is there mar'it ayin when you do something acceptable for you, but not to the general public?

Tags: halacha, minhag, modern-times

Is there mar'it ayin when you do something acceptable for you, but not to the general Jewish public? A couple of examples will highlight this issue:

Scenario 1: Person X books a table at a regular Vegan restaurant and worked with a reputable orthodox Rabbi to ensure that the food served is kosher (e.g., bishul akum, kosher products, bugs, etc.). Would it be considered mar'it ayin for Person X to go to such a restaurant since most people viewing this person will understandably not realise the lengths that he went to to ensure the kashrut standard?

Scenario 2: Person X is in a regular supermarket in America and buys regular hard cheese without a hechesher. Person X follows a psak that allows such a thing. Is it still considered mar'it ayin to purchase it in a regular store?

If they are considered mar'it ayin, why, and what could he do to remedy that fact?

---

Note: This question is similar to this question [Do I have to worry about "Maris Ayin" if my kashrut standards are different than the majority of a community?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44874/do-i-have-to-worry-about-maris-ayin-if-my-kashrut-standards-are-different-than). The present question is different in that the activity of the religious Jew has been either orchestrated such that this particular scenario is kosher, or that his following of a minority opinion is permissible to him but generally not for the general public.

Comment: I have found this guide to maris ayin very useful in the past: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Marit_Ayin/Suspicious_actions